# RadGrid Error is neither a DataColumn nor a DataRelation for table DefaultView

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

I am trying to set a primary key value with the DataKeyName attribute in the RadGrid but its giving me this cryptic error "cap_id is neither a DataColumn nor a DataRelation for table DefaultView." It is indeed the primary key of the table I specify in the RadGrid. How can I solve this?

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
        AllowSorting="True" CellSpacing="0" GridLines="None" 
        DataSourceID="sqlDataSourceCapabilities" AutoGenerateColumns="true"
        AutoGenerateDeleteColumn="True" AutoGenerateEditColumn="True" 
        onpagesizechanged="RadGrid1_PageSizeChanged" 
        onitemcommand="ProcessThisCommand">
        <ClientSettings>
            <Scrolling AllowScroll="True" UseStaticHeaders="True" />
        </ClientSettings>
        <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="cap_id" DataSourceID="sqlDataSourceCapabilities">
```

Comment: Could you move `DataSourceID` to `RadGrid` instead of `MasterTableView`? `<telerik:RadGrid ... DataSourceID="sqlDataSourceCapabilities">`

Comment: Its already there. See above. It still generates the same error.

Comment: I got it. I add to add the cap_index to the Select query of the sqlDataSource.

Answer (score 0):

You must Add the **Primary Key Field** of that particular table in the **Select Query**.

you can hide it later by using the visible at the end of Column.

`<telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Subject" visible="false">`